# wWhat we can do about that-every time after editing?

Tags: python, cmd, discord.py

I have a bot written in Python shell and each time to test something new I have to close/open a command prompt, write cd C:/.....  python bot.py. What we can do about that - every time after editing, do not write and do not activate many times is that all?

Here is the program

````
import discord

import math

from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

# Constant
DISCORD_TOKEN = "E"

FORTNITE_API_KEY = 'a'

LISTE = ['Wood', 'Carton', 'Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Platinum', 'Diamond', 'Ruby', 'Royality', 'Illuminati', 'Hackeur']
WOOD_B = 0.00
WOOD_E = 0.99
CARTON_B = 1.00
CARTON_E = 1.49
BRONZE_B = 1.50
BRONZE_E = 1.99
SILVER_B = 2.00
SILVER_E = 2.49
GOLD_B = 2.50
GOLD_E = 2.99
PLATINUM_B = 3.00
PLATINUM_E = 3.49
DIAMOND_B = 3.50
DIAMOND_E = 3.99
RUBY_B = 4.00
RUBY_E = 4.99
ROYALITY_B = 5.00
ROYALITY_E = 5.99
ILLUMINATI_B = 6.00
ILLUMINATI_E = 7.99
HACKEUR_B = 8.00
HACKEUR_E = 100

# Return the overall K/D of the fortnite player pass in parameter
def get_ratio(username):
    print(username)
    link = 'https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/' + username
    response = requests.get(link, headers={'TRN-Api-Key': FORTNITE_API_KEY})
    if response.status_code == 200:
        collection = response.json()
        if 'error' in collection:
            return "-1"
        else:
            for data_item in collection['lifeTimeStats']:
                if data_item['key'] == 'K/d':
                    ratio = data_item['value']
                    return ratio
        print("Invalid username")
        return "-1"
    else:
        print("Error recovering fortnite data")
        return "-2"

def print_nextLvl(begin, end, ratio):
    rang = end - begin
    if ratio >= rang * 0.00 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.059999 + begin:
        return '[■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.06 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.109999 + begin:
        return '[■■■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.11 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.159999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.16 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.209999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.21 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.259999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.26 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.309999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.31 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.359999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■■■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.36 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.409999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.41 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.459999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.46 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.509999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.51 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.559999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.56 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.609999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.61 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.659999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.66 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.709999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■□□□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.71 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.759999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■□□□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.76 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.809999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■□□□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.81 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.859999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■□□□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.86 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.909999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■□□□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.91 + begin and ratio <= rang * 0.959999 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■□□□□]'
    elif ratio >= rang * 0.96 + begin and ratio <= rang * 1.00 + begin:
        return '[■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■□□]'

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    # The command /patch return a link withvthe lastest patch note
    if message.content.startswith('/patch'):
        await message.channel.send('Last patchnotes: https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en/news')
    # The command /rank return attribute a rank according to the K/D of the user
    if message.content.startswith("/rank"):
        for list in LISTE:
            roles = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=list)
            await client.remove_roles(message.author, roles)
        username = '{0.author.display_name}'.format(message)
        ratio = float(get_ratio(username))
        print(ratio)
        if ratio >= WOOD_B and ratio <= WOOD_E:
            role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=LISTE[0])
            msg = ("{0.author.mention} Your have been ranked " + role.name).format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
            msgRatio = "Next level: " + str(ratio) + "k/d  **→**  " + str(CARTON_B) + "k/d"
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msgRatio)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, print_nextLvl(WOOD_B, WOOD_E, ratio))
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        elif ratio >= CARTON_B and ratio <= CARTON_E:
            role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=LISTE[1])
            msg = ("{0.author.mention} Your have been ranked " + role.name).format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
            msgRatio = "Next level: " + str(ratio) + "k/d  **→**  " + str(BRONZE_B) + "k/d"
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msgRatio)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, print_nextLvl(CARTON_B, CARTON_E, ratio))
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        elif ratio >= BRONZE_B and ratio <= BRONZE_E:
            role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=LISTE[2])
            msg = ("{0.author.mention} Your have been ranked " + role.name).format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
            msgRatio = "Next level: " + str(ratio) + "k/d  **→**  " + str(SILVER_B) + "k/d"
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msgRatio)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, print_nextLvl(BRONZE_B, BRONZE_E, ratio))
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        elif ratio >= SILVER_B and ratio <= SILVER_E:
            role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=LISTE[3])
            msg = ("{0.author.mention} Your have been ranked " + role.name).format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
            msgRatio = "Next level: " + str(ratio) + "k/d  **→**  " + str(GOLD_B) + "k/d"
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msgRatio)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, print_nextLvl(SILVER_B, SILVER_E, ratio))
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        elif ratio >= GOLD_B and ratio <= GOLD_E:
            role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=LISTE[4])
            msg = ("{0.author.mention} Your have been ranked " + role.name).format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
            msgRatio = "Next level: " + str(ratio) + "k/d  **→**  " + str(PLATINUM_B) + "k/d"
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msgRatio)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, print_nextLvl(GOLD_B, GOLD_E, ratio))
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        elif ratio >= PLATINUM_B and ratio <= PLATINUM_E:
            role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=LISTE[5])
            msg = ("{0.author.mention} Your have been ranked " + role.name).format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
            msgRatio = "Next level: " + str(ratio) + "k/d  **→**  " + str(DIAMOND_B) + "k/d"
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msgRatio)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, print_nextLvl(PLATINUM_B, PLATINUM_E, ratio))
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        elif ratio >= DIAMOND_B and ratio <= DIAMOND_E:
            role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=LISTE[6])
            msg = ("{0.author.mention} Your have been ranked " + role.name).format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
            msgRatio = "Next level: " + str(ratio) + "k/d  **→**  " + str(RUBY_B) + "k/d"
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msgRatio)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, print_nextLvl(DIAMOND_B, DIAMOND_E, ratio))
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        elif ratio >= RUBY_B and ratio <= RUBY_E:
            role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=LISTE[7])
            msg = ("{0.author.mention} Your have been ranked " + role.name).format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
            msgRatio = "Next level: " + str(ratio) + "k/d  **→**  " + str(ROYALITY_B) + "k/d"
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msgRatio)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, print_nextLvl(RUBY_B, RUBY_E, ratio))
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        elif ratio >= ROYALITY_B and ratio <= ROYALITY_E:
            role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=LISTE[8])
            msg = ("{0.author.mention} Your have been ranked " + role.name).format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
            msgRatio = "Next level: " + str(ratio) + "k/d  **→**  " + str(ILLUMINATI_B) + "k/d"
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msgRatio)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, print_nextLvl(ROYALITY_B, ROYALITY_E, ratio))
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        elif ratio >= ILLUMINATI_B and ratio <= ILLUMINATI_E:
            role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=LISTE[9])
            msg = ("{0.author.mention} Your have been ranked " + role.name).format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
            msgRatio = "Next level: " + str(ratio) + "k/d  **→**  " + str(HACKEUR_B) + "k/d"
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msgRatio)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, print_nextLvl(ILLUMINATI_B, ILLUMINATI_E, ratio))
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        elif ratio >= HACKEUR_B:
            role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=LISTE[10])
            msg = ("{0.author.mention} Your have been ranked " + role.name).format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
            msgRatio = "Your ratio: " + str(ratio) + " K/D \n Max level! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ "
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msgRatio)
            await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
        elif ratio == -1:
            msg = "Your discord name is not a fortnite username! Use the command ```/nick YOUR_FORTNITE_USERNAME``` first!".format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
        elif ratio == -2:
            msg = "The fortnite servers are offline. Try again later!".format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

    client.load_extension('cog')

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print('client ready')

    @client.command()
    async def load():
        client.unload_extension('cog')
        client.load_extension('cog')

client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
````

@Benjin Here is such a mistake

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot2.py", line 9, in <module>
    client.load_extension('cog')
  File "C:\Users\FeNka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 696, in load_extension
    lib = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\FeNka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\bot\test1\cog.py", line 1
    From discord.ext import commands
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x03A98290>
```

Can the system reboot command to do everything inside bot.py

Comment: @Carcigenicate What tools for example??I have Atom, Sublime, VC

Comment: In the console press Ctrl+C then up arrow, then enter.

Comment: @CatCat Not work/

Comment: `from discord.ext` isn't valid Python.  It looks like half of an import statement `from discord.ext import commands`

Comment: Case matters, `from` not `From`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write everything in separate files called cogs, then you can use a command to reload the cogs. In this way, you can edit your cog files and use the command in discord to reload the cogs. You can name the files anything you want, but make sure you then use `client.load_extension('FILENAME')`.

With the below example, using the command "load" in discord will reload the `cog.py` file. You can edit the file and use "load" to apply the edits. Note that if you want to edit the main file, in this case `bot.py`, you still have to restart the bot.

**bot.py**

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

client.load_extension('cog')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('client ready')

@client.command()
async def load():
    client.unload_extension('cog')
    client.load_extension('cog')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

**cog.py**

```
from discord.ext import commands

class TestCog:

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.counter = 0

    @commands.command()
    async def add(self):
        self.counter += 1
        await self.bot.say('Counter is now %d' % self.counter)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(TestCog(bot))
```

Comment: @Benjin.cmd log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot2.py", line 5, in <module>
    client.load_extension('cog')
  File "C:\Users\FeNka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 696, in load_extension
    lib = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\FeNka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that is giving you this error.

Comment: Here is changed, are looking

Comment: That's only your error, not your code. Please include both, otherwise it will be difficult to answer your question.

Comment: And now what do you say?

Comment: Your code is a single file, meaning my proposed answer will not work. You need to create a separate file that has your commands and events in it and load it using `client.load_extension`, as in my example.